# The difference between quoted and unquoted attribute selector in CSS

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I was wondering what is the difference between quoted and unquoted attributes in css selectors and does that have any effect on performance.

```
input[type="text"]
```

/

```
input[type=text]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The above are the same. The quotes are optional for [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), but must be used when it is a [string](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).

Some common examples of being a [string](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) include:

- Containing a space ()
- Beginning with a digit (`0-9`)
- Containing a hyphen after a digit

Here's [the full spec of an identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

---

Further reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: so it's safe to assume there is no difference in performance?

Comment: @EmreTürkiş If there is, it's dependent on the browser and essentially immeasurable.

Comment: There are a number of other circumstances that require quoting the value. Once you realize this, you basically have no reason to even *think* about performance issues in such cases anymore.

Comment: "Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings. [CSS21]" Anything that distinguishes an identifier from a string basically. The most common other gotcha is when the value begins with a digit since an ident cannot begin with a digit.